# Assigning DataSource from Modal Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following code in my model controller. Even though I have a series of objects in the data, however it does not show/update the bar column on the chart.

I wonder where am I doing wrong or missing?

**Model.js**

```
var theDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: allData,
    group: {
        field: "series"
    },
    sort: {
        field: "category",
        dir: "asc"
    }
});
chart.dataSource = theDataSource;
chart.refresh();
```

**View.js**

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    title: {
        text: "Selection",
        color: "white"
    },
    theme:"Metro",
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "column",
        stack: true,
    },
    series: [{
        field: "value",
    }]
})
```

Comment: FOr the listview, I think you do listview.dataSource.refresh();  Maybe the same applies here?  Or does the chart have a dataBind() method?

Comment: @BrianMains, I have refresh() method.

Comment: Can you also include a data sample?

Comment: Yes I have debugged and I have seen the dataset, it is not empty.

Comment: Have you tried `chart.setDataSource(theDataSource);`?

Comment: Nicholas, could you please post your approach as an answer and I will mark it. It works a charm! Please also include the difference between `chart.dataSource = theDataSource;` vs `chart.setDataSource(theDataSource);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setDataSource()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#methods-setDataSource) to set the datasource, this will notify the chart that the datasource has changed.

```
var theDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: allData,
    group: {
        field: "series"
    },
    sort: {
        field: "category",
        dir: "asc"
    }
});
chart.setDataSource(theDataSource);
```